# Does Wifi Direct support a mesh/tree topology for P2P or does it only support one Access Point with multiple clients?

Tags: android-wifi, wifi-direct

I'm currently reading the Android docs on WiFi Direct. I know a WiFi Direct access point can have multiple clients, but can WiFi Direct support a tree or mesh topology? For example, if I have a conference hall and everyone turns on their phone, can I send data from node 1 to node n, even if the two nodes are k branches away?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43505854/4288004 this answer and the linked paper will help you. The answer is: by default, no, but you might make it work with effort and depending on the way you route it, you might need root